# How to generate _id pages for movies using NUXT generated from API fetched from the movie DB

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure of this project]

This is how page looks like:

[image: Main movies page]

I have got all necessary data from props, but I fail to understand how to generate dynamic id pages.
**I want to generate dynamic ~/movies/_id pages, based on the id pulled from an array from API.
And that pages just have to get Title, picture and overview from API object.** So those two are questions.

Movies.vue is parent page. movieComp is component I have used to v-for on, to display list of a movies received from the array from API. Below every movie picture is a details button that should lead to that movie details (based on the id received from API).

_id.vue is a page that I want to display based on the id received from API.

This is code in movies.vue (parent).

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap min-h-full w-screen">
        <movieComp v-for="result in movies.results" 
          :key="result.id" 
          :movie-title="result.original_title" 
          :base-img-path="result.poster_path"
          :movie-id="result.id" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import movieComp from '../components/movieComp.vue'
export default {
  components: { movieComp },
    
    data() {
      return {
        movies: [],
        apiKey: "7ed6d2f608b8f66d8fd54d5f11c9e7d4",
        baseURL: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=7ed6d2f608b8f66d8fd54d5f11c9e7d4",
        }
    },
    
    async fetch() {
      this.movies = await fetch(
        this.baseURL
      ).then(res => res.json())
      console.log(this.movies)

    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This is code in movieComp (component, child).

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-col bg-gray-100 p-2">
      <h1 class="text-xl">{{movieTitle}}</h1>
      <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300'+baseImgPath" alt="Image">
      <nuxt-link :to="`/movies/${movieId}`" >Details</nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    movieTitle: {
      type: String,
      default: "Title"
    },
    baseImgPath: {
      type: String,
      default: "/464N3J1i6L5SsazPmX9m3q1GiZ3.jpg"
    },
    movieId :{
      default: 436969
    }
  },
  data (){
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
  }
  
  
  
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This is code in _id.vue (in same folder pages as movies.vue).

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p>id is {{$route.params.id}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        movies: [],
        apiKey: "7ed6d2f608b8f66d8fd54d5f11c9e7d4",
        baseURL: "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=7ed6d2f608b8f66d8fd54d5f11c9e7d4",
        }
    },
    
    async fetch() {
      this.movies = await fetch(
        this.baseURL
      ).then(res => res.json())
      console.log(this.movies)

    },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And this is an object that fetch gets me from an API.

```
{
  page: 1,
  results: [
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/rAgsOIhqRS6tUthmHoqnqh9PIAE.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 436969,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'The Suicide Squad',
      overview: 'Supervillains Harley Quinn, Bloodsport, Peacemaker and a collection of nutty cons at Belle Reve prison join the super-secret, super-shady Task Force X as they are dropped off at the remote, enemy-infused island of Corto Maltese.',
      popularity: 10896.338,
      poster_path: '/kb4s0ML0iVZlG6wAKbbs9NAm6X.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-28',
      title: 'The Suicide Squad',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8.1,
      vote_count: 1809
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/dq18nCTTLpy9PmtzZI6Y2yAgdw5.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 497698,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Black Widow',
      overview: 'Natasha Romanoff, also known as Black Widow, confronts the darker parts of her ledger when a dangerous conspiracy with ties to her past arises. Pursued by a force that will stop at nothing to bring her down, Natasha must deal with her history as a spy and the broken relationships left in her wake long before she became an Avenger.',
      popularity: 3267.6,
      poster_path: '/qAZ0pzat24kLdO3o8ejmbLxyOac.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-07',
      title: 'Black Widow',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.8,
      vote_count: 4067
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/bwBmo4I3fqMsVvVtamyVJHXGnLF.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 451048,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Jungle Cruise',
      overview: 'Dr. Lily Houghton enlists the aid of wisecracking skipper Frank Wolff to take her down the Amazon in his dilapidated boat. Together, they search for an ancient tree that holds the power to heal – a discovery that will change the future of medicine.',
      popularity: 2961.286,
      poster_path: '/9dKCd55IuTT5QRs989m9Qlb7d2B.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-28',
      title: 'Jungle Cruise',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8,
      vote_count: 1494
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/rUoGZuscSG4fQP3I56ndadu2A8E.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 729720,
      original_language: 'fr',
      original_title: 'Le Dernier Mercenaire',
      overview: 'A mysterious former secret service agent must urgently return to France when his estranged son  is falsely accused of arms and drug trafficking by the government, following a blunder by an overzealous bureaucrat and a mafia operation.',
      popularity: 3213.38,
      poster_path: '/ttpKJ7XQxDZV252KNEHXtykYT41.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-30',
      title: 'The Last Mercenary',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 6.7,
      vote_count: 162
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/wjQXZTlFM3PVEUmKf1sUajjygqT.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 581726,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Infinite',
      overview: 'Evan McCauley has skills he never learned and memories of places he has never visited. Self-medicated and on the brink of a mental breakdown, a secret group that call themselves “Infinites” come to his rescue, revealing that his memories are real.',
      popularity: 2930.632,
      poster_path: '/niw2AKHz6XmwiRMLWaoyAOAti0G.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-06-10',
      title: 'Infinite',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.3,
      vote_count: 622
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/xXHZeb1yhJvnSHPzZDqee0zfMb6.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 385128,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'F9',
      overview: "Dominic Toretto and his crew battle the most skilled assassin and high-performance driver they've ever encountered: his forsaken brother.",
      popularity: 2792.565,
      poster_path: '/bOFaAXmWWXC3Rbv4u4uM9ZSzRXP.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-05-19',
      title: 'F9',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.7,
      vote_count: 2534
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/8s4h9friP6Ci3adRGahHARVd76E.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 379686,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Space Jam: A New Legacy',
      overview: "When LeBron and his young son Dom are trapped in a digital space by a rogue A.I., LeBron must get them home safe by leading Bugs, Lola Bunny and the whole gang of notoriously undisciplined Looney Tunes to victory over the A.I.'s digitized champions on the court. It's Tunes versus Goons in the highest-stakes challenge of his life.",
      popularity: 2450.211,
      poster_path: '/5bFK5d3mVTAvBCXi5NPWH0tYjKl.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-08',
      title: 'Space Jam: A New Legacy',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.6,
      vote_count: 1654
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/6tPOZmNQ1tbzlhcMmyhYN1a1dEh.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 809968,
      original_language: 'pl',
      original_title: 'Bartkowiak',
      overview: "After his brother dies in a car crash, a disgraced MMA fighter takes over the family nightclub — and soon learns his sibling's death wasn’t an accident.",
      popularity: 2137.345,
      poster_path: '/kOVko9u2CSwpU8zGj14Pzei6Eco.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-28',
      title: 'Bartkowiak',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 5.9,
      vote_count: 60
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/gX5UrH1TLVVBwI7WxplW43BD6Z1.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 459151,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'The Boss Baby: Family Business',
      overview: 'The Templeton brothers — Tim and his Boss Baby little bro Ted — have become adults and drifted away from each other. But a new boss baby with a cutting-edge approach and a can-do attitude is about to bring them together again … and inspire a new family business.',
      popularity: 1910.775,
      poster_path: '/5dExO5G2iaaTxYnLIFKLWofDzyI.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-01',
      title: 'The Boss Baby: Family Business',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.8,
      vote_count: 1127
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/620hnMVLu6RSZW6a5rwO8gqpt0t.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 508943,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Luca',
      overview: 'Luca and his best friend Alberto experience an unforgettable summer on the Italian Riviera. But all the fun is threatened by a deeply-held secret: they are sea monsters from another world just below the water’s surface.',
      popularity: 1928.955,
      poster_path: '/jTswp6KyDYKtvC52GbHagrZbGvD.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-06-17',
      title: 'Luca',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8.1,
      vote_count: 3759
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/yizL4cEKsVvl17Wc1mGEIrQtM2F.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 588228,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'The Tomorrow War',
      overview: 'The world is stunned when a group of time travelers arrive from the year 2051 to deliver an urgent message: Thirty years in the future, mankind is losing a global war against a deadly alien species. The only hope for survival is for soldiers and civilians from the present to be transported to the future and join the fight. Among those recruited is high school teacher and family man Dan Forester. Determined to save the world for his young daughter, Dan teams up with a brilliant scientist and his estranged father in a desperate quest to rewrite the fate of the planet.',
      popularity: 1856.431,
      poster_path: '/34nDCQZwaEvsy4CFO5hkGRFDCVU.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-06-30',
      title: 'The Tomorrow War',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8.2,
      vote_count: 3340
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/wPjtacig0kIkVcTQmXoNt6jbMwo.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 617502,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Jolt',
      overview: 'Lindy is an acid-tongued woman with rage issues who controls her temper by shocking herself with an electrode vest. One day she makes a connection with Justin, who gives her a glimmer of hope for a shock-free future, but when he’s murdered she launches herself on a revenge-fueled rampage in pursuit of his killer.',
      popularity: 1751.19,
      poster_path: '/gYZAHan5CHPFXORpQMvOjCTug4E.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-15',
      title: 'Jolt',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 6.7,
      vote_count: 453
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/tehpKMsls621GT9WUQie2Ft6LmP.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 602223,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'The Forever Purge',
      overview: 'All the rules are broken as a sect of lawless marauders decides that the annual Purge does not stop at daybreak and instead should never end as they chase a group of immigrants who they want to punish because of their harsh historical past.',
      popularity: 1568.853,
      poster_path: '/hpYAhOJ8EdB6s9LKMBABmvrN2KV.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-06-30',
      title: 'The Forever Purge',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.7,
      vote_count: 903
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/6MKr3KgOLmzOP6MSuZERO41Lpkt.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 337404,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Cruella',
      overview: 'In 1970s London amidst the punk rock revolution, a young grifter named Estella is determined to make a name for herself with her designs. She befriends a pair of young thieves who appreciate her appetite for mischief, and together they are able to build a life for themselves on the London streets. One day, Estella’s flair for fashion catches the eye of the Baroness von Hellman, a fashion legend who is devastatingly chic and terrifyingly haute. But their relationship sets in motion a course of events and revelations that will cause Estella to embrace her wicked side and become the raucous, fashionable and revenge-bent Cruella.',
      popularity: 1202.782,
      poster_path: '/wToO8opxkGwKgSfJ1JK8tGvkG6U.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-05-26',
      title: 'Cruella',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8.4,
      vote_count: 4656
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/heMC3jAjQPNSlr1n9mZKUQ58EOE.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 672322,
      original_language: 'ja',
      original_title: 'るろうに剣心 最終章 The Beginning',
      overview: 'Before he was a protector, Kenshin was a fearsome assassin known as Battosai. But when he meets the gentle Tomoe Yukishiro, a beautiful young woman who carries a huge burden in her heart which would change the life of Battosai forever.',
      popularity: 1177.554,
      poster_path: '/rODS466qSdrwMlGdbUwPENhDN2c.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-06-04',
      title: 'Rurouni Kenshin: The Beginning',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.8,
      vote_count: 76
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/j28p5VwI5ieZnNwfeuZ5Ve3mPsn.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 550988,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Free Guy',
      overview: 'A bank teller called Guy realizes he is a background character in an open world video game called Free City that will soon go offline.',
      popularity: 1124.537,
      poster_path: '/yc2IfL701hGkNHRgzmF4C6VKO14.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-08-11',
      title: 'Free Guy',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8.2,
      vote_count: 37
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/oYiPf8oR2ZrjvGIVzGTw1BZihDP.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 153104,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Wicked Minds',
      overview: 'A young man returns home from college to find his father remarried, until the sudden murder of his father leaves everyone suspect.',
      popularity: 731.369,
      poster_path: '/A6A15cDR8mpdOxW4y7UzFanzbM0.jpg',
      release_date: '2003-03-01',
      title: 'Wicked Minds',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 4.9,
      vote_count: 6
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/77tui163estZrQ78NBggqDB4n2C.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 637649,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Wrath of Man',
      overview: "A cold and mysterious new security guard for a Los Angeles cash truck company surprises his co-workers when he unleashes precision skills during a heist. The crew is left wondering who he is and where he came from. Soon, the marksman's ultimate motive becomes clear as he takes dramatic and irrevocable steps to settle a score.",
      popularity: 993.934,
      poster_path: '/M7SUK85sKjaStg4TKhlAVyGlz3.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-04-22',
      title: 'Wrath of Man',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 7.9,
      vote_count: 1824
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/iJ2HVOZT9Kjayrhy21pbGIJs9ey.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 525660,
      original_language: 'cn',
      original_title: '真·三国无双',
      overview: 'Warlords, warriors and statesmen wage a battle for supremacy in this fantasy tale based on the hit video games and the "Romance of the Three Kingdoms."',
      popularity: 984.798,
      poster_path: '/7BCTdek5LFHglcgl7shsm7igJAH.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-04-29',
      title: 'Dynasty Warriors',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 6.3,
      vote_count: 51
    },
    {
      adult: false,
      backdrop_path: '/3OwaKVZf3A2NdnarqKbwzFEhKir.jpg',
      genre_ids: [Array],
      id: 730840,
      original_language: 'en',
      original_title: 'Trollhunters: Rise of the Titans',
      overview: 'Arcadia may look like an ordinary town, but it lies at the center of magical and mystical lines that makes it a nexus for many battles among otherworldly creatures, including trolls, aliens, and wizards. Now, various heroes will team-up in an epic adventure where they must fight the Arcane Order for control over the magic that binds them all together.',
      popularity: 896.391,
      poster_path: '/zvUNFeTz0Sssb210wSiIiHRjA4W.jpg',
      release_date: '2021-07-21',
      title: 'Trollhunters: Rise of the Titans',
      video: false,
      vote_average: 8,
      vote_count: 139
    }
  ],
  total_pages: 500,
  total_results: 10000
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create a movies subfolder in which you add _id.vue and movies.vue (renamed index.vue).

You should have the folowing folder structure:

```
movies/
  index.vue (previously movies.vue)
  _id.vue
```